# The property 'PropertyName' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<decimal>'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I got this problem when I try to create the database with EntityFramework Core:

> The property 'Rating.RatingScores' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Here is the class:

```
public class Rating
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<decimal> RatingScores { get; set; }

    public decimal Score
    {
        set => Score = value;
        get => Math.Round(RatingScores.Sum() / RatingScores.Count, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: As the error message suggests, try using `[NotMapped]` as this doesn't look like something you are storing in the database.  If you want to store the values in the database, create a new class for the new table, and then map it accordingly (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30202171/1073631).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the Rating class has multiple RatingScores you have a one-to-many relationship and the RatingScores property needs its own table, you therefore need to create a new class.

```
Class RatingScore 
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public decimal RtSc { get; set; }
}
```

Then the Rating property will look like this:

```
public List<RatingScore> MyRatingScores { get; set; }
```

However if each Rating has one RatingScore, your property should not be a collection.

```
public RatingScore MyRatingScore { get; Set; }
```

Answer (score 6):

When you really need to put `multiple values in single column` can use below way

Let's say you want to create only **one table** for below class

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<int> Values { get; set; }
}
```

First create a `converter`, which will control `.net values to db values and vice versa`

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.ValueConversion;
 
    public class IntListToStringValueConverter : ValueConverter<IEnumerable<int>, string>
    {
        public IntListToStringValueConverter() : base(le => ListToString(le), (s => StringToList(s)))
        {

        }
        public static string ListToString(IEnumerable<int> value)
        {
            if (value==null || value.Count()==0)
            {
                return null;
            }
 
            return value.Join(',');
        }

        public static IEnumerable<int> StringToList(string value)
        {  
            if (value==null || value==string.Empty)
            {
                return null;
            }

            return value.Split(',').Select(i => Convert.ToInt32(i)); ; 
            
        }
    }
```

And `DbContext` should have below method

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         .....

        var IntValueConverter = new IntListToStringValueConverter();

        modelBuilder
            .Entity<SomeClass>()
            .Property(e => e.Values)//Property
            .HasConversion(IntValueConverter);

    }
```

**Done!!** IT should work

Comment: Thanks! This works like a charm. It also complained about a comparator, so the code looked like this at the end: `a.Property(e => e.Time).HasConversion(listToStringValueConverter).Metadata.SetValueComparer(valueComparer); `

Answer (score 2):

For EntityFramework Core. This solution will help you to save proper data in DB as well as, whenever the result comes back from DB, it will convert to List.

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  modelBuilder.Entity<WebhookSubscription>()
      .Property(p => p.Webhooks)
      .HasConversion(v => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(v),
                     v => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(v));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here is my error and I just found what the problem is.

> The property 'LogEntry.Timestamp' could not be mapped because it is of type 'Instant', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

Actually its fairly clear what it is trying to say.

I have overridden OnModelCreating but I missed a trivial thing.

Here is my dbcontext class.

```
public class ExtendedElsaMigrationsDbContext : SqlServerContext
{
    public ExtendedElsaMigrationsDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        // I should not comment out this base method call.
        // base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

        modelBuilder.ConfigureExtendedElsaDbContext();
    }
}
```

Note that I had commented out the base method call. And that is what is causing the problem.

The overridden method should be as follows.

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        //    //modelBuilder.Entity<User>();

        modelBuilder.ConfigureExtendedElsaDbContext();
    }
```

Summary: Don't forget to call the base method when you are overriding a method. Many times base method don't do much, so we ignore them. But some times they do. So always call the base methods.