# Creating A Database With List<int> Property Through Code First Approach

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a database using MySQL with my entities by a code first approach, but I got some errors when I tried. That error was:

> InvalidOperationException: The property
>   'SymptomousInBodySublocations.HealthSymptomLocationIDs' could not be
>   mapped, because it is of type 'List' which is not a supported
>   primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this
>   property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using
>   'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.

So, I guessed that I could get an error like this, but honestly I don't any idea about how to handle it.

**My Method:**

```
public static void InsertData()
{
    List<SymptomousInBodySublocations> SymtomsInBodySublocationsList = MedicService.SymptomsInBodySublocations();

    var semptominbodylocation = new SymptomousInBodySublocations();

    var context = new SymptomsRepo();

    using (context)
    {
        context.Database.EnsureCreated();
        foreach(SymptomousInBodySublocations symptomousInBodySublocations in SymtomsInBodySublocationsList)
        {
            semptominbodylocation.ID = symptomousInBodySublocations.ID;
            semptominbodylocation.Name = symptomousInBodySublocations.Name;
            semptominbodylocation.HasRedFlag = symptomousInBodySublocations.HasRedFlag;
            semptominbodylocation.HealthSymptomLocationIDs = symptomousInBodySublocations.HealthSymptomLocationIDs;
            semptominbodylocation.ProfName = symptomousInBodySublocations.ProfName;
            semptominbodylocation.Synonyms = symptomousInBodySublocations.Synonyms;
            context.SymptomousInBodySublocations.Add(semptominbodylocation);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

**My Entity Class:**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SymptomousInBodySublocations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasRedFlag { get; set; }
    public List<int> HealthSymptomLocationIDs { get; set; }
    public string ProfName { get; set; }
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

**My Context Class:**

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class SymptomsRepo : DbContext
{
    public SymptomsRepo(){  }

    public SymptomsRepo(DbContextOptions<SymptomsRepo> options) :base(options){}
    public DbSet<SymptomousInBodySublocations> SymptomousInBodySublocations {get; set;}

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
      optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("server=localhost;database=Symptoms;user=root;password=password");
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

How can I add it as a list or as a single feature inside a table?

Comment: Try `ICollection`, but here is some further reading, scroll down a bit https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @TheMuffinMan thank you for your suggetion but i havent any foreign relationship between my tables.

Comment: What column type do you expect the database engine to use for a list of primitive values?

Comment: @yaakov I also don't know the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Halin,

I'm pretty sure your question is an exact duplicate of this thread:

[The property 'PropertyName' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<decimal>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659280/the-property-propertyname-could-not-be-mapped-because-it-is-of-type-listdec)

Which I found by copying your error message and pasting it into Google.

Your problem is exactly what the error message says. When mapping a C# class to a database table, you can not map a `List<>` because there is no `List<>` type in SQL. Meaning, no SQL column can have a type of a `List<>`. String, Int, DateTime... no problem. But a single cell in a SQL table is not designed to contain a collection. It can only contain a single value.

You either need to remove this field from your class, or decorate it with `[NotMapped]` as follows:

```
public class SymptomousInBodySublocations
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool HasRedFlag { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<int> HealthSymptomLocationIDs { get; set; }
    public string ProfName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes it's a dublicated. I agree about it. Especially i asked is there any way to create it anyway? But i voted your entry thank you so much, I created without that properties.