# ASP.Net Core 3.1 MVC - MultiSelect with List of Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

So, basically the aim is:

User selects multiple 'categories' for a book (genres) from a select list. Some examples are:

- Action and Adventure
- Classics
- Comic Book or Graphic Novel

After the user selects 1 or more (so multiple), they save the book to a database.

Functiality wise, everything worked just fine when I was dealing with singular genres (the genre was saved as a single string), but I need to have support for multiple genres.

The first thing I did was simply change the `string Category` to `List<string> Categories`, but that caused the error seen here: [StackOverflow issue, which was solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659280/the-property-propertyname-could-not-be-mapped-because-it-is-of-type-listdec)
I tried the solution that 'TuPack' offered, and that error went away... but it led to a whole new issue.

You're up to speed on where I am now:
In order to get any results out of my `<select></select>` , I have to do this:

```
<select asp-for="CategoryIds[0].CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Language"
        class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="">Please choose book language</option>                    
</select>
```

That certainly works.. for getting the first category the user selects. That's all though.

As for the code so far, relevance wise... I'll cut off the db related stuff, since the issue occurs long before there:

Controller:

```
public async Task<ViewResult> AddNewBookAsync(bool isSuccess = false, int bookId = 0)
        {
            var model = new BookModel();
            
            ViewBag.Language = new SelectList(await _languageRepository.GetLanguages(), "Id", "Name");

            ViewBag.IsSucess = isSuccess;
            ViewBag.BookId = bookId;            
            return View(model);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewBook(BookModel bookModel)
        {


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                int id = await _bookRepository.AddNewBook(bookModel);
                if(id > 0)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(AddNewBook), new { isSuccess = true, bookId = true });
                }
            }



            ViewBag.Language = new SelectList(await _languageRepository.GetLanguages(), "Id", "Name");
            return View();
        }
```

BookModel:

```
public class BookModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [StringLength(100, MinimumLength = 5)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage ="Please enter the title of your book")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the author's name")]
        public string Author { get; set; }
        [StringLength(500)]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please choose the language of your book")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Genre")]
        public List<Categories> CategoryIds { get; set; } = new List<Categories>();

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the total pages")]
        [Display(Name = "Total pages of book")]
        public int? TotalPages  { get; set; }
    }
```

I showed the relevant Html code previously, so won't post it again.

Visuals:
Example Input:
[image: Example Input]
Current Output:
[image: Current Output]

Category Id 1 is 'Action And Adventure'.

By the way, I'm sure it is quite easy to tell, but this is just a 'practice project'. I don't want to make big changes to the main project I'm working on without actually knowing what I'm doing.

Update:
After changing `CategoryIds[0].CategoryId` and running it with the exact same values as before, I get:
[image: 0 object results]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**

[image]

I used to add a `IList<SelectListItem>` property to `Book` model and store multiple categories in `CategoryIds` property. It works on me.

> Codes of controller

```
    public IList<SelectListItem> GetCategories()
    {
        var categories = new List<Category>
        {
            new Category {Id = 1, CategoryName = "Action and Adventure"},
            new Category {Id = 2, CategoryName = "Classics"},
            new Category {Id = 3, CategoryName = "Comic Book or Graphic Novel"},
        };  // here you can load categories from DB, this is only for test
        


        var categoryListItem = categories
       .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CategoryName, Value = x.Id.ToString() })
       .ToList();

        return categoryListItem;
    }


    [Route("/books/add")]
    public IActionResult _AddNewBooks()
    {
        var model = new BookModel { CategoryList = GetCategories() };

        return View(model);
    }


    [Route("/books/addnewbook")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddNewBook(BookModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //int id = await _bookRepository.AddNewBook(bookModel);
            //if (id > 0)
            //{
            //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(AddNewBook), new { isSuccess = true, bookId = true });
            //}
        }

        //ViewBag.Language = new SelectList(await _languageRepository.GetLanguages(), "Id", "Name");
        model.CategoryList = GetCategories();

        return View();

    }
```

> Codes of model

```
public class BookModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public IList<SelectListItem> CategoryList { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select at last 1 Category")]
    public List<int> CategoryIds { get; set; }


    public BookModel(){
        CategoryList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    }
}


public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
}
```

> Codes of view

```
<select asp-for="CategoryIds" asp-items="Model.CategoryList" 
           placeholder="Select Categories" 
           onchange="console.log($(this).children(':selected').length)" 
           class="search-box form-control">
</select>
```

@MJDeveloping,

**1>** You are using `ViewBag.Language`  as items of  `Category`. I suggest
you return `Categories` to the view.

**2>** `asp-for` should be `CategoryIds`.

```
<select asp-for="CategoryIds" asp-items="ViewBag.Language"
        class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
   <option value="">Please choose book language</option>                    
</select>
```

Comment: Opps! That Language is left over from the lesson I'm following - They did languages as a select... but it didn't make too much sense to be able to select multiple languages, so I swapped it to categories

Comment: In regards to using "CategoriesIds" though- I get 0 objects in the List. Will edit post with a picture.

Comment: Hi,@ MJDeveloping, the relationship between Book and Category has change to [Many to Many](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key#many-to-many) from your description. And you could try to use  build new model in new relationship.  Please feel free to ask if you have any questions with it.

Comment: Thanks, @Lightman. I've gone ahead and created a Many to Many relationship.. after opening it up in SSMS, I've confirmed that both the Books and Categories table have a one to many relationships to the BookCatagories table. Currently:

```asp-for="Categories"``` and "Categories" is ```public List<BookCatagory> Categories {get; set;}```

Oh right, I should probably mention: The source of the categories is a DB, not a enum or hardcoded in the program.

Comment: Opps-forgot the importance bit- the end result looked no different to the start-if I select a certain element, it works, but trying to operate on the whole array returns 0 results

Comment: The reason of returning 0 results is the values you selected is not mapped to the `CategoryIds` in right way.

Comment: I see- how should I go about mapping it then? Feel free to ask for code samples- it's just a test project, so nothing private or confidential

Comment: `public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Language")] BookModel bookModel,IList<int> BookCategories)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220606/discussion-between-lightman-and-mjdeveloping).