# .NET Core : is not a valid member access expression

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework, .net-core

In .NET Core, I have a model class like this:

```
public class City
{
    public Geometry Center { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

By row query, I am fetching my data from Postgres:

```
var result = await _context.Cities.FromSql($"SELECT jt.* FROM (SELECT ARRAY_AGG( p.\"relatedCities\") AS unique_vals FROM public.\"Provinces\" as p WHERE p.\"externalId\" = {provId}) q LEFT JOIN public.\"Cities\" jt ON jt.\"externalId\" = ANY(q.unique_vals);").ToListAsync();

return Ok(result);
```

When my result is returned to the consumer, I want to instead of sending geometry I send coordinate. I am using `NetTopologySuite.Geometries`.

I have `OnModelCreating` method in my `dbcontext` class. I added :

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>()
    .Property(e => e.Center.Coordinate);
```

but I get this error :

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[1]
>
> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>
> System.ArgumentException: The expression 'e => e.Center.Coordinate' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')
>
> at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ExpressionExtensions.GetInternalMemberAccess[TMemberInfo](LambdaExpression memberAccessExpression)

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong: the lambda expression must represent a **simple property or field access**. `e => e.Center` would fit this description but `e => e.Center.Coordinate` does not.

Comment: How can I return its coordinate? is it possible?@NeilT

Comment: You could try adding another (read-only) property, `public Coordinate Coord => this.Center.Coordinate;`, to your `City` class, then use `e => e.Coord` as the expression?

Comment: I did but I got ` The 'Coordinate' property 'City. Coord' could not be mapped because the database provider does not support this type. Consider converting the property value to a type supported by the database using a value converter.` @NeilT

Comment: You'll need to provide a value converter, mapping the `Coordinate` type to a type that the database can support (say, some JSON text representing a co-ordinate). For an example of how to do this, take a look at the answer by Moumit here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51659280/the-property-propertyname-could-not-be-mapped-because-it-is-of-type-listdec

Comment: Thanks my friend, I guess getter is a simplest way

Answer (score 0):

try doing:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<City>().OwnsOne(c => c.Center, owned => {
    owned.Property(e => e.Coordinate); 
});
```